# How certain technologies got their names?

Tags: tomcat, ant, glassfish, names

How did `Ant`, `Maven`, `Tomcat`, `Glass Fish`, etc got their names? 
I noticed these are all animal (-related) names.

Comment: Creative and/or bored developers, mostly.

Comment: Maybe asking Apache Foundation directly is better than asking here :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the rest, here is the link that explains why Glassfish was named. https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FaqWhyName

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ant FAQ Page](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#ant-name): According to Ant's original author, James Duncan Davidson, the name is an acronym for "Another Neat Tool".